# Python error given when announcing a earlier defined variable

Tags: python

I created a menu where I can display variables that the user put in. There are set by default if the user puts in nothing. Problem is I get an error when I execute the module. Variables that are set by default: `tab = "True"` and `amount = "N/A"`

code: `def menu(): print(""" * = Optional`

```
    1. Start the application. 
    2. Set crate.
    3. Set link for crate. *
    4. Settings. *
""")
menu_qsone = str(input("> "))
if menu_qsone == "4":
    clear()
    settings()
```

```
def settings():
    print("Settings: ")
    print("1. Open a tab when the program is launched." + (tab))
    print("2. Times the script will be used." + (amount))
    print("3. Return to menu.")
    qs_one = str(input("> "))
    if qs_one == "1":
        clear()
        if tab == "True":
            tab = "False"
            clear()
            settings()
        if tab == "False":
            tab = "True"
            clear()
            settings()

    if qs_one == "2":
        clear()
        print("How many times would you like to run the script?")
        qs_two = str(input("> "))
        amount = (qs_two)
        clear()
        settings()

    if qs_one == "3":
        clear()
        menu()

menu()
```

Error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\Desktop\PauzeProject\MainFile.py", line 63, in <module>
    menu()
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\Desktop\PauzeProject\MainFile.py", line 32, in menu
    settings()
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\Desktop\PauzeProject\MainFile.py", line 36, in settings
    print("1. Open a tab when the program is launched." + (tab))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tab' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You haven't set `tab` at the start of `settings`. You need to set it before you use it in the line indicated in the error.

Comment: if I do that will I be able to call the variables in another define function?

Comment: Variables are local to the function they're set in. If you need a value inside of a function that's set in another function, `return` the value from the one function, then pass it in as an argument to the function its needed in.

Comment: At the top you say 'Variables that are set by default: tab = "True" and amount = "N/A"'. Where are you setting them?

Comment: Edit; see obove code

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. If that's the same code you've already posted though, what value do you expect `tab` to have at the top of `settings` before the `if qs_one == "1":` code is run?

Comment: I'll use your earlier given comment. I'll place the variables in another define function and overwrite them there. Lets say I put the variables in `def variables                          
 example = "example'` can I use `variables(example) = "1" ` then?

Comment: @Carcigenicate that needs to be "True", its set on the top of my code snippet.

Comment: I only mentioned another function because you had asked "will I be able to call the variables in another define function". Having a separate function just to define variables is unnecessary in the majority of cases. You haven't posted a [mcve] of what you're trying to do, so I'm guessing what your intent is. You're getting the error because you're trying to use a variable before it's been set, so the answer is to set it before you try to use it. Where you set it though depends on a lot of factors, and you haven't given enough context for us to say definitively.

Comment: You're saying `tab` is set in the global scope? Then you need `global tab` at the top of `settings`. Globals are poor practice, but that will fix your error if you're using them.

Comment: I typed it as `"True"` and not as `True` If that is what you mean.

Comment: I'll try `global` Edit: is this good? `global(tab = "True")`

Comment: This worked, I didn't see I needed to put it on the top of the settings define function. I'm closing the question now and thanks for the help.

Comment: Just as a note, that's why it's important to post a [mcve]. Knowing that you were using globals was an important detail that you neglected.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Still thanks for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def settings():

    global tab
    global amount
    print("Settings: ")
    print("1. Open a tab when the program is launched." + (tab))
    print("2. Times the script will be used." + (amount))
    print("3. Return to menu.")

    qs_one = str(input("> "))
    if qs_one == "1":
        clear()

        if tab == "True":
            tab = "False"
            clear()
            settings()

        if tab == "False":
            tab = "True"
            clear()
            settings()

    if qs_one == "2":
        clear()
        print("How many times would you like to run the script?")
        qs_two = str(input("> "))
        amount = (qs_two)
        clear()
        settings()

    if qs_one == "3":
        clear()
        menu()

menu()
```

Comment: I'll just note, you can post the code to [codereview.se] to request improvement suggestions once the code is complete and works as intended. Some things, like the use of global variables, and your use of `"True"` instead of `True` can be improved.